# Translating "Love has no age, no limits, and no end" into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Would someone be able to help me translate the following into Latin?

> Love has no age, no limits, and no end.

Comment: It seems that you have created two user accounts. See [this page](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for information about merging them. When you have your questions assigned to a registered account, you will be able to comment on answers and otherwise use the site more flexibly. The reputation you have earned from the two questions will also be combined if you merge. (Answers on this site are supposed to be used only for answering questions. Therefore some of your answers have been converted to comments, and this can lead to an automatic answer ban.)

Answer (score 3):

This is, I think, 'love' in the sense of 1 Corinthians 13,13, *nunc autem manet fides spes caritas tria haec maior autem his est caritas*. Trying to stay in keeping with the style of the original, I would write *est caritati neque aetas nec fines nec exitus*, '[there] is for love neither age, nor limit, nor end'.

Comment: Since John Galsworthy's original quote is, I think, "Love has no age, no limit; and no death", _exitus_ can indeed be quite appropriate here. A very minor problem of Tom's translation is the ambiguity of _exitus_ in this context: i.e., after Nom.pl. _fines_, it is not clear if _exitus_ must be interpreted as Nom. sg. (intended reading, I think, as synonym of _mors_) or as Nom. pl (as synonym of _fines_).

Comment: I changed my mind several times before submitting the answer : should it be _est_ or _sunt_? There doesn't seem to be a hard-and-fast rule for the verb's number in such cases, and I usually settle for agreement with the nearest subject. It's not a big deal!

Comment: I agree that both _est_ and _sunt_ are possible in this construction and both sound natural, but my minor point above had to do with the ambiguity of _exitus_ in that context (NB: this ambiguity remains whatever copular agreement _est_ or _sunt_ is chosen in that context).

Comment: thank you, tom. using your translation, would it be correct to capitalize the word  “’Est’, and omit commas (as in your text as written?)

Comment: Personally, I'd put it all in capitals, like all Roman public monuments used.

Comment: commas, or no commas?

Comment: Definitely, no commas!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

> *Amori nulla est aetas, nullus limes, nullus finis.*

This is a fairly direct translation of the original English phrase.
I think a possessive dative with *nullus* is a nice choice, but there is freedom in picking the nouns.
I recommend taking a look at my choices in any of [the many online Latin dictionaries](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79).
The words *limes* and *finis* are quite close to each other in Latin, but one can reasonably read them as "limit" and "end", respectively.

Comment: As for your interesting proposal that "a possessive dative with _nullus_ is a nice choice" here, I was wondering if there is a relevant stylistic difference between repeating _nullus_ and _nec_ (cf. Tom's translation supra). Another minor point: unlike _finis_, is _limes_ really appropriate in this context (i.e., when talking about love)?

Comment: @Mitomino The difference between using three copies of *nullus* or *nec* is to a large extent the difference between asyndeton and polysyndeton. Either way, the expression gets certain power from repetition. I find *nullus* to be somewhat more emphatic, so I chose it. // I'm not sure about the choice of *limes*. It means a number of things, not just fortifications. I'd gladly welcome new ideas!

Comment: There is a curious analogy between English, Italian, and Latin, by which *end*, *fine*, and *finis* both mean "objective" (as in *to what end?*) and "conclusion/limit" (as in *the end of the year*). However, in Italian the noun is masculine in the former case, and feminine in the latter, making me wonder whether it's the same in Latin...

Comment: @giobrach Please ask that as a separate question! I'd be very interesting in knowing how gender effects meaning for words like this.